# Adding buttons in ARCore Sceneform for the rotation and zooming?

Tags: android, 3d, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to add a 3D model in my android app, this app works fine(places a 3D model on the screen tap, rotate it with the finger gestures and zoom it with pinching). i am trying to make this finger zooming and rotation with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by getting your model cuurent position. Below method can be used on your button click. Hope this help you

```
private void modleMovement(TransformableNode node, String moveMent) {
    Vector3 currentPosition = new Vector3();
    Vector3 move = new Vector3();

    try {
        currentPosition = Objects.requireNonNull(node.getLocalPosition());

        if (moveMent.equals("down")) {
            move.set(currentPosition.x, (float) (currentPosition.y - 0.1), currentPosition.z);
            localPosition = move;
        }

        if (moveMent.equals("up")) {

            move.set(currentPosition.x, (float) (currentPosition.y + 0.1), currentPosition.z);
            localPosition = move;
        }

        if (moveMent.equals("right_move")) {

            move.set((float) (currentPosition.x + 0.1), currentPosition.y, currentPosition.z);
            localPosition = move;
        }

        if (moveMent.equals("left_move")) {

            move.set((float) (currentPosition.x - 0.1), currentPosition.y, currentPosition.z);
            localPosition = move;
        }
         if (moveMent.equals("rotate_left")) {
            localPosition = currentPosition;
            rotateLeft(node, objAxis, currentPosition);
        }

        if (moveMent.equals("rotate_right")) {
            localPosition = currentPosition;
            rotateRight(node, objAxis, currentPosition);
        }

        if (moveMent.equals("zoom_in")) {
            move.set(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, (float) (currentPosition.z + 0.1));
            localPosition = move;
        }

        if (moveMent.equals("zoom_out")) {
            move.set(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, (float) (currentPosition.z - 0.1));
            localPosition = move;
        }


        node.setLocalPosition(move);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```